# HTTPListener (or alternative?): keep connection alive

Tags: .net, http, httplistener

I have two applications communicating using a HTTP protocol. One application uses a `HTTPListener` to receive data from the other. This works quite well.
Due to the fact, that it's usually only the two applications communication, I would like to keep the connection alive for as long as possible. The `KeepAlive` property of HttpListenerRequest is set to true (this is the default) but the connection seems to get closed once I send the response.

I can not find any settings for HttpListener such as time outs etc. Is this even possible with this class or are there any more suitable alternatives available?

Answer (score 3):

`Timeout` is a client thing - whoever requests waits for a timeout.

`KeepAlive` is an optional header which requests to server to keep the connection alive while server is not obliged to. This keeping alive **spans multiple requests** which I believe is not what you are after.

Behaviour you are after can be achieved by `chunked encoding`.

have a listen to this [podcast](http://hanselminutes.com/291/damian-edwards-explains-the-realtime-web-for-aspnet-with-signalr) you will get all answers.